# Distribution identification with respect to number of fitting parameters

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, fitting

I want to check a sample of measurements against different distributions in order to determine the underlying distribution. Distributions should be yielded based on probability or goodness-of-fit tests. An implementation of such an approach is given in [this implementation](http://www.aizac.info/simple-check-of-a-sample-against-80-distributions/). However, the proposed method there applies distributions with different number of parameters, for example Johnson S$_U$ distribution has four parameters while Normal Distribution has only 2, which sometimes affects the results in favour of distributions with more parameters.

For example analyzing 80 samples from a normal distribution yielded 8 distributions (*loggamma*, *nct*, *tukeylambda*, *invgamma*, *rdist*, *betaprime*, *lognorm*, *johnsonsu*) to be more likely than *norm*, all of them having 3+ parameters. How can I account for this effect?

Comment: If the fitting criteria, such as maximum likelihood, is nearly the same for those eight and for the normal, then using the distribution with fewer parameters seems reasonable.

Comment: I agree, but what exactly would be "nearly the same"? I would like a solid calculation of such a threshold.

Comment: I was making a general comment and have no formal threshold calculation. I think the threshold would have to be decided on a case-by-case basis depending on analytical requirement.

Comment: There can no formal threshold calculation.  It's not only on a case-by-case basis but requires subject matter knowledge and that can certainly change over time as objectives change and levels of risk taking change.  There is no natural threshold that is intrinsic in the data.  Any threshold comes from outside of the data and Statistics.  If it were otherwise, why would we need anybody but statisticians to make such decisions?  You can't (or rather shouldn't) guide your life with just P-values.  (OK.  End of sermon.)